# php loading in a terminal or similar

Tags: php, terminal

I was wondering is it possible to program php without it being able to get accesed from another computer, and is it possible to load it in a terminal or in something that is not a browser?

Comment: Sure. There's a PHP CLI SAPI.

Comment: Wow thank you for your incredible fast reaction!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux you can just type

```
php ExampleFile.php
```

On Windows you either put the php.exe in your PATH variable or do the same:

```
c:\PathToPhpInstallation\php.exe ExampleFile.php
```

to run the file without even having a webserver. You just need to have php installed.